# Дана строка текста.Между двумя точками упорядочить символы по возрастанию

Tags: c++, строки

Дана строка текста.. Известно, что в строке есть только две точки . Найти их порядковые номера. Далее упорядочить по возрастанию символы, расположенные между ними.

```
string s{ "The problem wasn't Dulce or his father.To discover and define those laws is the problem of history."};

size_t position = 0, position_1 = 0;
auto iter = search(s.cbegin(),s.cend(),".");
position = distance(s.cbegin(),iter);
position_1= distance(s.cbegin()+position,search(s.cbegin(),s.cend(),"."));
sort(s.cbegin() + position, s.cbegin()+position_1);

    for (auto str : s)
    {
        cout << str;
    }
cout << "\nFirst position:\t" << position << "\tSecond position:\t" << position_1 << endl;
```

Comment: На первый взгляд код выглядит нормально, в чем ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
    string s{ "The problem wasn't Dulce or his father.To "
              "discover and define those laws is the problem "
              "of history. Next sentence"};
    size_t p1, p2;
    p1 = s.find('.');
    p2 = s.find('.', p1+1); // результат не проверяем - 
                            // точки гарантированы условием
    cout << "\nFirst position:\t" << p1 
         << "\tSecond position:\t" << p2 <<
         endl;
    sort(s.begin() + p1 + 1, s.begin() + p2);
    cout << s << endl;
    }
```